# Can't publish package in npm

Tags: angular, npm

I've created a really simple Angular 4 library following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ngl817/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e).

Everything is fine, except for the publishing part. When I run: `npm publish dist` in console, I get this error:

> You do not have permission to publish "dist". Are you logged in as the correct user? : dist

I am logged in as the correct user, so I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Have you tried checking the permissions of your user to the `dist/` directory ? Also have you tried running `cd dist/ && npm publish` ?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi yes, I tried `cd dist/ && npm publish` but I still get the error

Comment: Then check the permissions of your user to the directory.

Comment: I have full control over it

Comment: You might want to include that in your question then, to avoid having this converstation again ;)

Comment: I suggest adding screenshots or the outputs of `whoami` and `ls -l | grep dist` from your application directory.

Comment: It looks like the problem is with npm and not the filesystem, some solutions suggest changing the `name` field in `package.json` because it may be already used, have you tried that ?

Comment: Have you tried opening cmd or whichever program you are using to run `npm publish dist` as an administrator?

Comment: @nick zoum yes, I tried it , didn't work

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I checked `https://npmjs.com/package/myPackage` for my package name but there are no results, so it's not a name problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. What I had to do, was removing `"private":true` from `package.json` inside the dist folder and then run `cd dist && npm publish`.